# C# ASP.NET Core [Inject] Attribute Usage for Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have been using dependency injection inside a constructor which has been working great. I have recently learned of the [Inject] attribute, but cannot seem to get it to work. Maybe it's not compatible or perhaps I am misusing it.

Registering it as a service in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserProfileService, UserProfileService>();
```

Using it as a property with the [Inject] attribute:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Inject]
private IUserProfileService _UserProfileService { get; set; }
```

When _UserProfileService is called upon, it has not been initialized and is still null. If I switch back to injecting it in the constructor, it works. Am I misusing the attribute or is it simply not possible?

ASP.Net Core 3.1, using Blazor

Comment: What does that property belong to?

Comment: Some interesting reading here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16294

Comment: Documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `[Inject]` attribute is solely applied to Blazor Components. Property injection will not be applied to registrations made to the `IServiceCollection`, even if you mark those properties with `[Inject]`. The built-in DI Container is not capable of applying property injection.

The sole reason for the existence of the `InjectAttribute` is to use the `@inject` tag in Razor pages. When you use the `@inject` tag, Blazor will generate a public property on your  Blazor Component that is marked with `[Inject]`.

Although [Property Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-property-injection/) is [described as a valid pattern](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-4/section-4-4) for practicing DI in [DIPP&P](https://mng.bz/BYNl) (section 4.4), the book also warns about the downsides of Property Injection, and the authors (Mark Seemann and I) state that:

> *When building applications [...] we never use **Property Injection**, and you should do so sparingly. Even though you might have a **Local Default** for a Dependency, **Constructor Injection** still provides you with a better alternative. **Constructor Injection** is simpler and more robust. You might think you need **Property Injection** to work around a cyclic Dependency, but that’s a code smell, as we’ll explain in chapter 6.*

So, whenever possible, refrain from using Property Injection and use Constructor Injection as your sole way to provide dependencies to a consumer.

Comment: I have a base class Base and sub classes Sub1, Sub2, …, SubN, and I want to add a injected property to Base, then I have to change all constructors of all Subs to forward that new property. Is there a standard pattern to work around this using Constructor Injection?

Comment: Hi @Panke, it's hard to give specific guidance with such generic example, but in general, you should prevent using base classes i.c.w. DI and prefer using [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) instead. There are many design principles, patterns, and refactorings that help with this. e.g. The [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), patterns like the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), and refactorings like [Facade Services](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).