# C# xUnit dependency injection

Tags: c#, xunit, .net-8.0

I am currently working on a project that relies on dependency injection. I want to create a test for it. How do I mock the service and pass it to the test subject?

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CustomService>(new (CustomService("Param")));

var app = builder.Build();
```

ClassToTest.cs

```
public Class ClassToTest
{
    [Inject]
    protected CustomService _customService { get; set; }

    public ClassToTest(string args)
    {
        // ...
    }
 
    public void MethodToTest()
    {
         var restult = CustomService.Get()
    }
}
```

`CustomService.cs`:

```
// .
// .
public string Get()
{
    return "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: You should follow common dependency injection patterns, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65633184/4308455) to a similar question by one of the authors of the must-read book *"Dependency Injection - Principles, Practices and Patterns"*. You should consider using constructor injection, if possible in your scenario.

Comment: In a test, if you need to test `CustomService`, then you can just instantiate it and call methods as you desire.

Comment: I use https://github.com/pengweiqhca/Xunit.DependencyInjection

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i solved it.

I endend up using a combination of @Julians and @Daniel Manns approach.

ClassToTest.cs

```
  protected ICustomService _customService { get; set; }

    public ClassToTest(string args, ICustomService cs)
    {
        _customService = cs;
        // ...
    }
```

Test.cs

```
 [Fact]
 var cs = new CustomService()
 var SUT = new ClassToTest("args", cs)
 // ...
```